# as3 how to play multiple movieclip

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, movieclip

there are 3 movieclip in the array. How is play all movieclip

```
var mc1:MovieClip;
var mc2:MovieClip;
var mc3:MovieClip;
var mcArray:Array=["mc1","mc2","mc3"];

mcArray.gotoAndStop(2);// ????????????
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/*
var mc1:MovieClip;
var mc2:MovieClip;
var mc3:MovieClip;
*/

// Assuming MovieClips are on stage with the correct instance names 
// and are accessible from the frame this code is on.
var mcArray:Array=[mc1, mc2, mc3];

for (var i:int = 0; i < mcArray.length; i ++) {
    mcArray[i].gotoAndStop(2);
}
```